# allocating random no. of bytes in c

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

How can I dynamically allocate random no. of bytes in C?

(say) **I want to allocate 10 GB of memory**, how can I do that and which function would be better to use here, as in malloc, realloc or calloc(since I am not aware of the difference b/w them).

Plus, can I put any type of data(and should the whole data be of the same type?) in the memory hence allocated?

Comment: A note: _I want to allocate 10 GB of memory_: That's significantly high amount of memory. Check if that entire memory has to be contiguous...

Answer (score 0):

There are four functions in C about it:

```
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
void *malloc(size_t size);
void free(void *ptr);
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

Function `malloc()` allocates `size` bytes. Function `calloc()` allocates `nmemb*size` bytes (i.e. it allocates memory for array consisted of `nmemb` elements; also this function clears allocated memory). Function `realloc()` changes size of allocated block. And `free()` returns memory back to system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use malloc or calloc

```
SomeType *pointername = (SomeType*) malloc(numberof bytes for aloc.);
SomeType *pointername = (SomeType*) calloc(n,numberof bytes);//alocates n*number of bytes,and clears that memory with zero bytes
```

Yes, you can place any data yuo want in that memory

Malloc should be faster I think because it doesnt clear memory.

Realloc is used when you allready have aloceated memory and you want to make it bigger or smaller.

All data must be same type only if you want to access it as na array:

```
x=pointername[i];
```

, insed of accesing it with pointers.